# Request failing due to CORS Access-Control-Origin

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

So I have an application that I am making a PATCH request to my API. When I make my request, it fails with

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:3001/wallets/freshtest@test.com' from origin 'https://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

However if I run a GET request, this issue does not occur. Here are both requests

**Working Fetch**

```
const promisofData = fetch(url).then(r=>r.json()).then(data => {
    return data[0].balance;
});
```

**Not Working Fetch**

```
fetch(url, {
       method: 'PATCH',
       mode: 'cors',
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       body: JSON.stringify(iMoney)
});
```

In my API I have made sure that any origin should be allowed

```
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
```

I have tried a few different modes in the not working fetch, but I am struggling to understand why the GET request will work, but the PATCH request fails?

**Update Edit**

So I went ahead and tried the same request and used Axios instead of Fetch to run my request and it worked perfectly. When working with fetch, I was referring to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch and it states the different options available. If I supply 1 request option, are the rest required ?

Comment: Have you checked the OPTIONS request on the wire to make sure it really has the headers you've specified in `app.use`? Perhaps it's being processed by a different route.

Comment: FWIW, the [CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#access-control-allow-methods-response-header) specifically refers to the [methods in RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1) when saying what values are valid for `Access-Control-Allowed-Methods`. The RFC doesn't specifically include `PATCH`, but does include `extension-method` which it defines as simply `token`, which seems like a catch-all for "yeah, just about any method." Do you have this problem cross-browser? Perhaps the browser you're using simply doesn't support CORS with extension methods...

Comment: It may be worth trying with a `POST` just to rule that out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So options is returning 200. Within the API application I am using morgan to log the requests. I am just using Chrome for it all. All the apps are running on localhost just different ports. This is the first time I have had this problem with any of the requests I have made throughout this whole application

Comment: But again, does that `OPTIONS` request have the headers? Also, I would definitely look at this from *outside* Express, not just inside it. Use Fiddler or similar to spy on what's sent to the browser (since last I checked, Chrome hides the `OPTIONS`request from you :-( ).